# Can I avoid using "%>%"?

Tags: r, rename

i am learning R alone. Here is a piece of code I found online, to name a variable (column):

```
df <- df %>% rename(employees = How.many.employees.does.your.company.or.organization.have.)
colnames(df)[2]
```

I don't understand this "%>%" thing. Can I avoid it ? What exactly does it do?
The "df <- df" means that I am going to do an operation in df (indeed, rename a variable)

thanks!

Comment: You can also assign column names from a vector, or just a single element, i.e. here `colnames(df)[2] <- "employees"` should do (if it is the second element, you can `match()` otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

`%>%` is the [pipe operator](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html). It comes from the `magrittr` package. The latest version of R supports its functionality natively with `|>`. As the link I've provided says, "pipes are a powerful tool for clearly expressing a sequence of multiple operations," but you can certainly work without them. The link provides a lot more detail about using pipes and the alternatives.

Comment: Can I ask if use of pipe operators slow down codes?

Comment: Pipes were once considered slower many years ago but I don't know if that's still a consideration with modern implementations. They're widely used, however, because of the advantages they bring in writing understandable and more easily maintainable code.

Answer (score 2):

`df <- df %>% rename(employees = How.many.employees.does.your.company.or.organization.have.) colnames(df)[2]`

is equivalent to

`df <- rename(df, employees = How.many.employees.does.your.company.or.organization.have.) colnames(df)[2]`

The pipe takes the object on the left of the pipe and inserts it into the expression on the right, by default as the first argument. This helps avoid nested  expressions which can be harder to read. So you could write `df %>% do_this %>% then_that %>% and_finally_this` instead of `and_finally_this(then_that(do_this(df)))`.

The performance cost of the `%>%` step will be negligible in any scenario I can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

> is equivalent to

```
df <- rename(df, employees = How.many.employees.does.your.company.or.organization.have.) colnames(df)[2]
```

Thank you for your answer. `<-` feels more "intuitive" to me at this point, but I will try to learn both. I'm at the very beginning...
I understand the usefulness of `%>%` if I have a long list of "things to do". Better than writing different lines, or using a lot of (((())))

Comment: You may also write `df %<>% rename(...)`, which is equivalent to `df <- df %>% rename(...)`. Note that here `%>%` does not replace the assignment `<-`, but a function call. That is, `x %>% f()` is equivalent to `f(x)`, and `x %>% f(y)` is equivalent to `f(x, y)`. Note that `x` is used as the first argument of `f`, with whatever additional arguments are specified after `%>%`. To pass `x` as the second argument, you would write `x %>% f(y, .)`, equivalent to `f(y, x)`.

Comment: When you will understand this notation better, you will find that it's **much** more pleasant that writing function calls, with loads of nested parentheses, and operations specified in the wrong order, i.e. when you want to apply operation `f` to a dataframe, `df` then operation `g`, then `h`, it's far more readable to write `df %>% f() %>% g() %>% h()` than `h(g(f(df)))`. The call syntax gets even worse when there are (possibly many) arguments to the operations.